# How to create readonly user at database level in postgres DB

Tags: database, postgresql

I have more than one database (in PostgreSQL), and every database has more than one schema, and I want to give the select permission on all databases(only database level, not schema level) for a particular user. Any suggestion for how this could be done.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/grant-access-to-all-tables-of-a-database.checked this link but its only for schema level.

Comment: [pg_read_all_data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html)

Comment: can you elaborate this

Comment: Review the referenced documentation. If you still have a specific question then post a new question (or update this one) about that issue.